# Is there any possible way to match the n'th character?

Tags: regex, perl

My input data as below. I want to group the word between the 6th and 7th position of the `-`.

```
my $sa = "a1a1a1-b1b1b1-c-ddd-eee-fff-gggggg-hHhH-iiii-j-KKKKK";
```

For this, the actual regex was

```
/[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+-([^-]+)-/
```

For to build the regex, I tried as below,

```
my $avc = "[^-]+-" x 5 . "([^-]+)-";

my $ar = qr"$avc";

$sa =~m/$ar/g;

print $1;
```

My doubt, Is there any options are available for within regex. Without using `x`. How can I do it in a single regex?

Comment: `/(?:[^-]+-){5}([^-]+)-/`

Comment: Don't, and use 'split'. `my $value =  ( split /-/, $sa ) [6];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [limiting repetition quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

```
/(?:[^-]+-){5}([^-]+)-/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/tE2qC7/1)

---

The capturing group can be within the repetitive group only the last one gets captured.

```
/(?:([^-]+)-){6}/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/sJ9sJ8/1)